# Is it possible to have QR codes read and added to a MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, qr-code, database

Is it possible to implement a system where someone can read QR codes that would then signal a process that basically "pings" a MongoDB attached to a website "incrementing some data value signifying the QR code got scanned?

I am not asking for a full on solution, just a simple "yes you are heading in the right direction with that logic!"

Comment: What you are talking about is having a QR code correspond to an URL that presents a Web API. Whatever that does is basically up to you as there is nothing stopping an API from doing whatever you want it to. The general question comes off as a little too broad to hang around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can certainly do that. This is how I would suggest to proceed. This is more like my opinion.

With QR you have 2 types of values which can be showed viz. Static-String or URL. You would be making use of the URL.

1. Develop a simple web application with the home URL - as www.example.com/app - **Simple GET**
2. You can write the request handler which accepts the routed URL, then has a logic to increment the mongo-entity - value
3. Then you can redirect you current request to some specified page.

Comment: Do you know how to execute mongodb commands like "db.collection.insert()" from a webserver html or php file?

Comment: You may use the MongoSDK for php from here - http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/ and a web app. It should be fairly easy.